# Difference between authorizing the user and allowing the controls

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am building an app and come from a non-cs background but can't find a crucial difference between the following two scenarios. Assume **Activity X** is to be made secure and available only for authorized people.

1. Scenario. The user enters the credentials and he/she is directed to **activity X** if the credentials are correct, which are stored in **firebase authentication**, he can now do the work required and if he presses the Logout now, then he/she is logged out **again using firebase authentication** and sent to the main page. [I am using firebase authentication for this]
2. Scenario. The user enters the credentials and he/she is directed to the **activity X** if the credentials are correct (**these credentials are matched for existing entities in the firebase real-time database**), he can now do the work required and if he presses the Logout button now, then he/she is redirected to the main page.

In both scenarios, I feel that only if the user knows the correct credentials he/she can access activity X, but I also think that **Scenario 2** is not the correct way to do so. Can you explain the security issues and pitfalls in scenario 2?

Regards. Please share your thoughts, members of the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. That's by far the simplest and most secure solution you can implement for your users. As soon as you implement Firebase Authentication, you can then set security rules for the other products that might use, Firestore, Realtime Database, and Cloud Storage.
2. Storing user credentials in Realtime Database can be considered a risk. Without authentication, you cannot write security rules. This means that anyone that knows your project ID can read and write data in your databases.

So I definitely recommend going ahead using option one. Since you tagged your question with [android](/questions/tagged/android), then I recommend checking some additional resources:

- [How To Authenticate to Firebase Using Email and Password in Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91)

Or:

- [How to authenticate to Firebase using Google One Tap in Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d)

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo, I appreciate you taking the time for answering it, just have a small doubt about the second pointer. How can someone know my firebase project ID without my google credentials?

Comment: There is no need to know the credentials in order to know the project ID. You can simply open your project in your Firebase Console, and you'll see that the URL contains the project ID.

Comment: thanks I got a lot of insights from the links. Sorry, I came back late, was busy learning, will seek and implement it for me, and will ask about any other issue if it arises. Thanks a lot, again.